# Including colors during background-color-changing on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, colors, background

I have this code that changes the background-color on scroll, but it only changes from the "beginning-color" to the "ending-color", is it possible to include another colors between them?

[**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/V4qh9/11/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){  

    var scroll_pos = 0;
    var animation_begin_pos = 0;
    var animation_end_pos = $(document).height();
    var beginning_color = new $.Color( 'rgb(140,212,208)' ); 
    var ending_color = new $.Color( 'rgb(145,216,247)' ); ;//what color we want to use in the end
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop(); 
        if(scroll_pos >= animation_begin_pos && scroll_pos <= animation_end_pos ) { 
           // console.log( 'scrolling and animating' );
            //we want to calculate the relevant transitional rgb value
            var percentScrolled = scroll_pos / ( animation_end_pos - animation_begin_pos );
            var newRed = beginning_color.red() + ( ( ending_color.red() - beginning_color.red() ) * percentScrolled );
            var newGreen = beginning_color.green() + ( ( ending_color.green() - beginning_color.green() ) * percentScrolled );
            var newBlue = beginning_color.blue() + ( ( ending_color.blue() - beginning_color.blue() ) * percentScrolled );
            var newColor = new $.Color( newRed, newGreen, newBlue );
            //console.log( newColor.red(), newColor.green(), newColor.blue() );
            $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: newColor }, 0);
        } else if ( scroll_pos > animation_end_pos ) {
             $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: ending_color }, 0);
        } else if ( scroll_pos < animation_begin_pos ) {
             $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: beginning_color }, 0);
        } else { }
    });
});
```

Comment: doesnt it already do that.

Comment: It does, but i mean specific colors, like red or green

Comment: so like this? var beginning_color = new $.Color( "red");

Comment: actually that works too. so i am still not sure what you are asking

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You'll need to write the logic for additional transitional zones though as currently there is only 1 (between 0 & page height)

Comment: Im sorry, i forgot to mention that i want 5 colors to display including the beginning and end

Answer (score 2):

**Updated** : with five background colors.

Just do the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        var colorCodes = ['red','blue','green','yellow','orange'];
        $(window).on('scroll',function(){
            var value = $('body').scrollTop()%5;
            $('body').animate({
                 backgroundColor: colorCodes[value]
            }, 100 );
        });
    });
```

Change the color codes based on the value of scrollTop().

Take a array of you own color codes and call them based on the scrollTop() value.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/V4qh9/14/)

Comment: Thank you i will use this, but can i make the transition between them gradually?

Comment: @JoãoRafaelMartins Ya ofcourse you can but I am not sure how. You need to search on internet or update your post or wait for other answers or your wish.

Comment: @JoãoRafaelMartins updated with transitions. set the value (which is `100`) to correct your transitions.

Comment: i tried that, but i'm trying to do like this: http://readymag.com/, and i cant understant its code

Answer (score 1):

create a random color code using the following script..

```
var colorcode= 'rgb('
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ','
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ','
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
```

Comment: But i need specific colors

Comment: @JoãoRafaelMartins define your specific colors in an array and call them based on the values.